# Inputted string must be exactly 10 characters

Tags: postgresql, varchar

I am creating a column in postgres that must only accept 10 characters. `VARCHAR(10)` works in the sense that it allows data to be a maximum of 10 characters, however i cant seem to figure out a way to define a minimum.

How can one do this using 11.5 psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constraint to the table that checks the length:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT check_min_len CHECK (length(col) >= 10);
```

Comment: Works nicely, thanks. could you break down what each component does?